# YOLO V3 Python on Ubuntu 18.04.05 LTS [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, ubuntu-18.04, yolo

Good afternoon to everyone, this is Alex from Spain, it's my first post on stackoverflow, despite I've been reading the forum for ages.

I've been working on a yolov3 code since may, it consists on a webcam that recognises a qr code and moves a webcam accordingly by sending the centroid coordinates to an arduino by serial communication. It's currently running on PyCharm with darknet.

It has been working perfectly until last friday, when Ubuntu installed some updates (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04). Since then, it doesn't recognize dev/ttyUSB0 anymore. At first it said the error number 2 `[Errno 2]: No such file or directory`, so I did `~$ sudo mknod /dev/ttyUSB0 c 180 0`, and then `~$ sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0`, what brought me to the current situation, that's described on the title `[Errno 19] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 19] No such device: '/dev/ttyUSB0'`.

When I do `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` on the terminal it answers `crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 180, 0 jul  5 15:29 /dev/ttyUSB0`.

To `usb-devices` it prints the following statement regarding to the camera:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  6 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0458 ProdID=708c Rev=04.27
S:  Manufacturer=KYE Systems Corp.
S:  Product=USB_Camera
S:  SerialNumber=200901010001
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
```

And to `lsusb -tv` it prints:

```
/:  Bus 08.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
```

According to the PyCharm, the faulty code is the following:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
cap.set(30, 10)
whT = 320
confThreshold = 0.5
nmsThreshold = 0.2
```

And the error itself is the following statement:

```
/home/alejandro/PycharmProjects/001YOLOV3/venv/bin/python /home/alejandro/PycharmProjects/002YOLOV3/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alejandro/PycharmProjects/001YOLOV3/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 322, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
OSError: [Errno 19] No such device: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alejandro/PycharmProjects/002YOLOV3/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
  File "/home/alejandro/PycharmProjects/001YOLOV3/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/home/alejandro/PycharmProjects/001YOLOV3/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 325, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 19] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 19] No such device: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Whatever more data you could need, please make me know,

Thanks in advance for your help,

Alex

---

Update in the comments section.

Comment: `mknod /dev/ttyUSB0 c 180 0` -- I'm not sure about Ubuntu 18, but I believe this command is an anachronism. Point is, that creating the device node (filesystem entry) doesn't create the device. In the old times, `/dev` contained every possible device and the kernel decided whether anything was attached to it. Nowadays, we have automatisms that create and remove those device nodes. So, in short, you need to find out why the kernel doesn't recognize your device suddenly.

Comment: Good afternoon Ulrich, thanks for your reply. Today when I tried to run the code it jumped back to `serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'`, it doesn't show Errno 19 anymore. I've tried `lsusb` again with this result: `Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0458:708c KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) Genius WideCam F100`. I've also tried `~$ cd /sys/class/tty/`, and then `/sys/class/tty$ readlink ttyUSB0`, but I got no answer.

Comment: I've tried to change the webcam to this one: https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:03f0-e407 but the problem hasn't changed at all, it still makes the same statements. My kernel version according to `~$ uname -r` is `5.4.0-77-generic`

Comment: @AlexDesco probably your kernel is enumerating the USB webcam on some other device. Try running `dmesg -w`  and plug in your webcam. It'll list any kernel errors or let you know the exact `/dev/` node where it mounted. Replace the new `/dev/` node in the code.

Comment: @AbhijitNathwani thanks for your answer, this is what I got:
```
[10446.560465] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[10446.911635] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0458, idProduct=708c, bcdDevice= 4.27
[10446.911637] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[10446.911639] usb 1-1: Product: USB_Camera
[10446.911640] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: KYE Systems Corp.
```

Comment: [10446.911641] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[10446.924261] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB_Camera (0458:708c)
[10446.944179] input: USB_Camera: USB_Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:05:00.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input19

Comment: @AbhijitNathwani I've changed the `/dev/` to `ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 9600)`, but still brings the same [Errno 2]

Comment: You cannot change the `dev` path unless you have a device on the same path. It'll throw `No such file or directory` as there actually isn't anything there. Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/848390/666006 to identify where your USB webcam is mounted.

Comment: @AbhijitNathwani I installed `~$ sudo apt-get install v4l-utils`, and after that, `~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices` got me these results: USB_Camera: USB_Camera (usb-0000:0a:00.3-1):
 /dev/video0
 /dev/video1
I've run `~$ sudo v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --all` and I got:
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
 Driver name   : uvcvideo
 Card type     : USB_Camera: USB_Camera
 Bus info      : usb-0000:0a:00.3-1
 Driver version: 5.4.119

Comment: Also, when running `~$ sudo v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video1 --all` I got the following: Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
 Driver name   : uvcvideo
 Card type     : USB_Camera: USB_Camera
 Bus info      : usb-0000:0a:00.3-1
 Driver version: 5.4.119
 Capabilities  : 0x84A00001
  Video Capture
  Metadata Capture
  Streaming
  Extended Pix Format
  Device Capabilities
 Device Caps   : 0x04A00000
  Metadata Capture
  Streaming
  Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2 // 
Should I change /dev/ to /dev/video0? That brings me `Could not configure port: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')`

Comment: I'm sorry for asking too many things, I'm new on Ubuntu and I'm kinda lost with it

Comment: Ahh. The problem is you're connecting the USB camera as a serial device. The video camera frames are correctly captured using `cv.VideoCapture`. Your Arduino may have changed the `/dev/` name. Try the `dmesg -w` and plug in the Arduino serial cable to find the new name. Sorry I missed that part.

Comment: @AbhijitNathwani This is what I got when running `dmesg -w`: [15767.487078] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[15767.487080] usb 1-1: Product: USB_Camera
[15767.487081] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: KYE Systems Corp.
[15767.487082] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[15767.502089] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB_Camera (0458:708c)
[15767.522528] input: USB_Camera: USB_Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:05:00.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input21

Comment: [15779.335791] usb 7-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[15779.497789] usb 7-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64

Comment: And this for the Arduino: [15779.497791] usb 7-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[15779.497792] usb 7-1: Product: USB Serial
[15779.554571] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[15779.554581] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[15779.556195] usbcore: registered new interface driver ch341
[15779.556206] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for ch341-uart
[15779.556222] ch341 7-1:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[15779.567876] usb 7-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0

Comment: According to this, ttyUSB0 is being used by the Arduino Nano, so the question is where is the camera connected??

Comment: @AlexDesco Correct. The Arduino is now connected to `/dev/ttyUSB0` and your camera is connected to `/dev/video0` which is accessed by the `VideoCapture(0)` Note `0` here is the video device number. Your program in theory should now work with `/dev/ttyUSB0` in `serial.Serial()`

Comment: @AbhijitNathwani lot's of thanks! It is working now!